# iOS - Shuffle/Randomize order of objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to shuffle/randomize the order of the items inside my NSMutableArray when method reloadData is executed. I tried the below, but console keeps throwing me the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI
>   exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x1748b2c60'

Any idea why this might be? I'm stumped.

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, retain) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)reloadData:(id)sender
{


     NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
            [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



                self.neighbourData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;

                [self.tableView reloadData];

                NSUInteger count = [self.neighbourData count];
                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
                    int nElements = count - i;
                    int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
                    [self.neighbourData exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
                }


                NSLog(@"This is the neighbourdata %@",self.neighbourData);


            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that `responseObject` is actually a non-mutable `NSArray`. The cast you applied simply lies to the compiler but it doesn't actually change anything at runtime.

Change:

```
self.neighbourData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
```

to:

```
self.neighbourData = [(NSArray *)responseObject mutableCopy];
```

Comment: To the OP, this is an important point to learn. Casting a variable to a different type does not change the type of the underlying object. It simply forces the compiler to *think* it is a different type. If the object is **not** a mutable array, you need a function (`mutableCopy`) that takes the immutable array as a parameter and hands you back a new mutable array that contains the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

For production you really ought to use the built in [Fisher-Yates shuffle in Gamekit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkrandomsource/1501128-arraybyshufflingobjects).  If you are doing this for leaning purposes then the problem is in the line:

```
int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
```

You are making a random number from the first to the last element **and then you are adding i to it**. Clearly this means that your index can now be out of bounds.  Get rid of the **+ i**.

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to address the issue presented in the question.

Comment: This is a valid point, but as rmaddy said, it isn't an answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

`self.neighbourData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;`

You have to make sure that your responseObject is an instance of NSMutableArray here. Even though you cast the type responseObject to NSMutableArray, it will crash if it's not an instance of NSMutableArray because it dose not have a  exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:. In this case your responseObject is a NSArray instance, your could change the code to：

 `NSArray *tmp = (NSArray *)responseObject;
 self.neighbourData = [tmp mutableCopy];`

I think this works for you.